# Store positioning information from each element (JQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each, offset

*Pleasantries*
I've been playing around with this idea for a couple of days but can't seem to get a good grasp of it. I feel I'm almost there, but could use some help. I'm probably going to slap myself right in the head when I get an answer.

*Actual Problem*
I have a series of `<articles>` in my `<section>`, they are generated with php (and TWIG). The `<article>` tags have an image and a paragraph within them. On the page, only the image is visible. Once the user clicks on the image, the article expands horizontally and the paragraph is revealed. The article also animates left, thus taking up the entire width of the section and leaving all other articles hidden behind it.

I have accomplished this portion of the effect without problem. The real issue is getting the article back to where it originally was. Within the article is a "Close" `<button>`. Once the button is clicked, the effect needs to be reversed (ie. The article returns to original size, only showing the image, and returns to its original position.)

*Current Theory*
I think I need to retrieve the offset().left information from each article per section, and make sure it's associated with its respective article, so that the article knows where to go once the "Close" button is clicked. I'm of course open to different interpretations.

I've been trying to use the `$.each`, `each()`, `$.map`, `map()` and `toArray()` functions to know avail.

*Actual Code*

```
/*CSS*/
section > article.window {
                           width:170px; 
                           height:200px; 
                           padding:0; 
                           margin:4px 0 0 4px; 
                           position:relative; 
                           float:left; 
                           overflow:hidden; 
                         }
section > article.window:nth-child(1) {margin-left:0;}
```

```
<!--HTML-->
<article class="window">
    <img alt="Title-1" />
    <p><!-- I'm a paragraph filled with text --></p>
    <button class="sClose">Close</button>
</article>
<article class="window">
    <!-- Ditto + 2 more -->
</article>
```

*Failed Attempt Example*

```
function winSlide() {
    var aO = $(this).parent().offset()
    var aOL = aO.left
    var dO = $(this).offset()
    var dOL = dO.left
    var dOT = dO.top
    var adTravel = dOL-aOL

    $(this).addClass('windowOP');
    $(this).children('div').animate({left:-(adTravel-3)+'px', width:'740px'},250)
    $(this).children('div').append('<button class="sClose">Close</button>');

    $(this).unbind('click', winSlide);
}
$('.window').on('click', winSlide)

$('.window').on('click', 'button.sClose', function() {
    var wW = $(this).parents('.window').width()
    var aO = $(this).parents('section').offset()
    var aOL = aO.left
    var pOL = $(this).parents('.window').offset().left
    var apTravel = pOL - aOL

    $(this).parent('div').animate({left:'+='+apTravel+'px'},250).delay(250, function() {$(this).animate({width:wW+'px'},250); $('.window').removeClass('windowOP');})

    $('.window').bind('click', winSlide)

})
```

Before you go scratching your head, I have to make a note that this attempt involved an extra div within the article. The idea was to have the article's overflow set to visible `(.addclass('windowOP'))` with the div moving around freely. This method actually did work... almost. The animation would fail after it fired off a second time. Also for some reason when closing the first article, the left margin was property was ignored.

ie.
First time a window is clicked: Performs open animation flawlessly
First time window's close button is clicked: Performs close animation flawlessly, returns original position
Second time SAME window is clicked: Animation fails, but opens to correct size
Second time window's close button is clicked (if visible): Nothing happens

Thank you for your patience. If you need anymore information, just ask.

**EDIT**
Added a jsfiddle after tinkering with Flambino's code.

http://jsfiddle.net/6RV88/66/

The articles that are not clicked need to remain where they are. Having problems achieving that now.

Comment: A jsFiddle would get you an answer quicker ! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go for storing the offsets, you can use jQuery's `.data` method to store data "on" the elements and retrieve it later:

```
// Store offset before any animations
// (using .each here, but it could also be done in a click handler,
// before starting the animation)
$(".window").each(function () {
  $(this).data("closedOffset", $(this).position());
});

// Retrieve the offsets later
$('.window').on('click', 'button.sClose', function() {
  var originalOffset = $(this).data("originalOffset");
  // ...
});
```

[Here's a (very) simple jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6RV88/)

Update: And [here's a more fleshed-out one](http://jsfiddle.net/DNLBK/2/)

Comment: This seems like it might work, going to test it with multiple articles next to each other to see if they preserve their own offset information. I'll get back to you in the morning.

Comment: After playing with the code you provided, I think I'm on the cusp of achieving the effect that I want. The problem is still that multiple articles do not stay in their original place once an article  is clicked. The other articles need to not move at all. I've linked a jsfiddle to show what I've come up with with your example. http://jsfiddle.net/6RV88/66/

Comment: @ABCaesar be careful about using that `element` variable. It's not the only thing causing trouble, but it's one. I used it because it referred to a single `article` element, but now that you've added some more, `element` refers to _all_ of then (since `element = $("article")`). So, inside click-handler you should use `$(this)` to ensure you're manipulating only the clicked element, and not all the others as well.

Comment: @ABCaesar Alright, [here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DNLBK/2/). The tricks were 1) fixing the elements as `position: absolute` right away (could be avoided, but easier this way), 2) fixing the aforementioned variable-usage, and 3) using `.position()` instead of `.offset()`. That last one was my mistake; we need the offset relative to the section (which `.position` gives us), _not_ the offset from the browser window (`.offset`).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, was not paying attention and this saved me. Thanks so much for your help. I was finally able to achieve the effect I wanted.

Comment: @ABCaesar No problem. I was scratching my head too until I realized the offset/position switcharoo I'd made. Don't forget to click the checkmark to mark my answer as accepted

Comment: But of course, I listed what the finished code looks like below if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Flambino

I was able to create the effect desired. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gck2Y/ or you can look below to see the code and some explanations.

Rather than having each article's offset be remembered, I used margins on the clicked article's siblings. It's not exactly pretty, but it works exceptionally well.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<section>
    <article>Click!</article>
    <article>Me Too</article>
    <article>Me Three</article>
    <article>I Aswell</article>
</section>
```

```
/* CSS */
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 404px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden
}

article {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: green;
    border-right:1px solid orange;
}

.expanded {z-index:2;}
```

```
//Javascript
var element = $("article");

element.on("click", function () {
    if( !$(this).hasClass("expanded") ) {
        $(this).addClass("expanded");

        $(this).data("originalOffset", $(this).offset().left);
        element.data("originalSize", {
            width: element.width(),
            height: element.height()
        });

        var aOffset = $(this).data("originalOffset");
        var aOuterWidth = $(this).outerWidth();

        if(!$(this).is('article:first-child')){
            $(this).prev().css('margin-right',aOuterWidth)
        } else {
            $(this).next().css('margin-left',aOuterWidth)
        }

        $(this).css({'position':'absolute','left':aOffset});
        $(this).animate({
            left: 0,
            width: "100%"                
        }, 500);
    } else {
        var offset = $(this).data("originalOffset");
        var size   = $(this).data("originalSize");
        $(this).animate({
            left: offset + "px",
            width: size.width + "px"                
        }, 500, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("expanded");
            $(this).prev().css('margin-right','0')
            $(this).next().css('margin-left','0')
            element.css({'position':'relative','left':0});
        });
    }
});​
```